# Check is not null in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`PostgreSQL 8.4`

I have the following piece of sql-script:

```
WHERE p.partner_id IS NOT NULL
    AND (let.external_transaction_registration_date IS NULL OR
 let.external_transaction_registration_date > :date)
```

Is it the correct way to check for either not-null or if null then there're no constratints should be applied? Does postgresql evalute an exression `E2` in `(E1 OR E2)` even if `E1` is true?

Comment: in this particular case, why would testing E2 be of any use? If E1 succeeds, then the value is obviously null, and cannot possibly be equal/greater-than/lest-than to anything else, including itself

Comment: @MarcB Maybe, but I would just like to know how postgresql evaluates `(E1 OR E2)`. Is it going to evaluate E2 if E1 is true?

Comment: @MarcB: did you see the `OR`? Your comment makes sense if those conditions where combined with an `AND` but using `x is null or x > something` does make sense.

Comment: @St.Antario: SQL does not "short-circuit". To my knowledge it always evaluates all conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, but `TRUE or anything` is going to be true

Comment: @MarcB: yes, but in this case the expression is aimed at the combination `false OR something`. This pattern is usually used if you want `null` to be smaller than the comparison date (which `x > :date` wouldn't be if `x` is null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does postgresql evalute an exression `E2` in `(E1 OR E2)` (even if `E1` is true)?

Maybe. It is unpredictable per [spec](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL):

> The order of evaluation of subexpressions is not defined. In particular, the inputs of an operator or function are not necessarily evaluated left-to-right or in any other fixed order.
>
> Furthermore, if the result of an expression can be determined by evaluating only some parts of it, then other subexpressions might not be evaluated at all.

But your expression is safe, [because](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html):

> SQL uses a three-valued logic system with true, false, and null, which represents "unknown".

In case of `NULL` values, evaluation goes as `(TRUE OR NULL)`, which is `TRUE`.

In fact both of these expressions are satisfying your needs (*either not-null or if null then there're no constratints should be applied*):

```
WHERE date_col IS NULL OR date_col > :date
-- vs:
WHERE date_col > :date OR date_col IS NULL
```

> Boolean expressions (`AND`/`OR`/`NOT` combinations) in those clauses can be reorganized in any manner allowed by the laws of Boolean algebra.

This also [applies](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) to [PostgreSQL 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-logical.html).